# How do I compile Whitepixel for Windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, passwords, mingw

## Background

Whitepixel is open source (GPLv3) GPU-accelerated password hash auditing software for AMD/ATI graphics cards.

- [Whitepixel site](http://whitepixel.zorinaq.com/)
- [Whitepixel direct download (.tar.bz2)](http://whitepixel.zorinaq.com/files/whitepixel-2.tar.bz2)
- [Whitepixel README](http://pastie.org/3104024)

## Question

I want to compile Whitepixel on Windows, and I found [a comment](http://pastie.org/3104032) that suggested it can, and has, been done.

To compile Whitepixel on Windows (Windows 7, 64-bit), what software do I need, and how do I use it?

From the comment, my guess is [mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip/download) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/), but it's really just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a MinGW environment is via installing the MSysGit "Net Install" - this will create you a full MinGW environment with a simple installer, then drop you in a Bash shell. From there, you can copy in the Whitepixel source and follow instructions similar to the Linux ones.

Comment: I installed msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.8-preview20111206.exe. Then I installed ATI Stream SDK and edited the make file. Then i tried to run make, and got these errors: http://i.imgur.com/7ZvX9.png

Comment: Neither
[CPPFLAGS = -I"~/Documents/AMD\ APP/include/"]
or
[CPPFLAGS = -I"/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/include"]
works